# What happens when "file_with_invalid_chars:<?>.txt" is passed to the MFC CFile class?

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, windows-7, mfc

**Note:** Needed to edit the title and question, as initially I thought the problem is with `::CreateFile[W]` - but it turns out, the error only happens on XP when I use MFC's Cfile class.

I am slightly confused by the behaviour of `CFile::Open(...)` (on Win7/64bit) when I pass the filename `file_with_invalid_chars:<?>.txt` to this function to request creation of the file.

On my Windows XP box, the call fails.

On my Win7/64 box, the call succeeds, creating a file named `file_with_invalid_chars`.

What's happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that this is due to a bugfix(?) in shlwapi.dll -

MFC's `CFile` class does some internal processing on the filename, and happens to call the [`PathStripToRoot` Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773757%28VS.85%29.aspx).

This function resides in Shlwapi.dll and Win7 is shipped with a newer version than Windows XP.

The Version in Windows XP apparently does not work correctly with file-paths containing ADS colon separated stream names.

Example:

- On XP `PathStripToRoot(L"C:\\temp\\file.txt:stream");`yields the string `C:\temp\file.txt:` which is incorrect and leads to an error return from `CFile::Open`
- On Win7, the same call yields the actual root `C:\`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing it's creating an [alternate data stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364404.aspx).  Seems odd that it would fail on XP, though.  The documentation says that characters legal for a file name are also legal for a stream name, though I guess that doesn't necessarily mean the inverse is true.  Maybe Windows 7 supports < and > in stream names and Windows XP doesn't.

Comment: Yes, the problem's got to do with ADS. But it turns out it's only with MFC Cfile, not with CreateFileW in general.